# Fetch records base on previous ID - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Please I want to fetch crops based on its `category id`, will be glad if this can be achieved without JavaScript

**Display page**

```
<div class="cat-list">
    <h3 class="cat-title">
        <a href="/filterByCategory/{{$category->cat_id}}">
            <i class="fa fa-car ln-shadow"></i>
            {{$category->cat_name}}<span class="count">{{$category->count()}}</span>
        </a>
        <span data-target=".cat-id-1" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn-cat-collapsed collapsed">
            <span class=" icon-down-open-big"></span>
        </span>
    </h3>
    <ul class="cat-collapse collapse in cat-id-1">
    @php
        $catID = $category->cat_id;
        //want to fetch crops base on the $catID and display in foreach
    @endphp
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Controller function**

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::all();

    $crops = Crop::all();

    return view('public.index' , compact('categories' , 'crops'));
}
```

**Crop Model**

```
public function category() 
{ 
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'cat_id', 'crop_cat')
}
```

**Category Model**

```
public function category() 
{ 
    return $this->hasmany(Category::class, 'crop_cat','cat_id') 
}
```

Comment: You've not outlined how a crop is related to a category. Post your database schema and/or model relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this method to your Category model:

```
public function crops() {
    return $this->hasMany(Crop::class, 'catID');
}
```

and this function to your Crop model:

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'catID');
}
```

After that you can basically loop through all categories on your blade template and in this loop echo out all crops of the current category. Then, this could look like this:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    {{ $category->name }}

    @foreach ($category->crops as $crop)
         {{ $crop->title }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

You can find more information about Eloquent relationships on Laravel [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships).